# Почему не получается с сохранением kartik GridView?

Tags: yii2

Собственно вот ссылки на само [расширение](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid) вот документация по сохранению с использованием [GridView](http://webtips.krajee.com/setup-editable-column-grid-view-manipulate-records/)

но есть необходимость вносить изменения в две модели поэтому преобразую код вот так в контролере

```
if (Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')) {
            $id = Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');
            $editableAttribute= Yii::$app->request->post('editableAttribute');
            $model = Transliter::findOne($id);
            $out = Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'message'=>'']);
            $posted = current($_POST['Transliter']);
            $post = ['Transliter' => $posted];
            if ($model->load($post)) {
                $model->$editableAttribute=$posted;
               if($model->save()){}else{
                    return var_dump($model->getErrors());
                }
                $output = '';
                $out = Json::encode(['output'=>$output, 'message'=>'']);
            }
            echo $out;
            return;
```

получаю ошибку `Internal Server Error` причем если за комментировать сохранения и вернуть модель вот так

```
if (Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')) {
            $id = Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');
            $editableAttribute= Yii::$app->request->post('editableAttribute');
            $model = Transliter::findOne($id);
            $out = Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'message'=>'']);
            $posted = current($_POST['Transliter']);
            $post = ['Transliter' => $posted];
            if ($model->load($post)) {
                $model->$editableAttribute=$posted;
            }
            echo $out;
            return var_dump($model->category);
```

то получаю что изменение есть но не сохранились. Дебаг выдает ошибку

```
yii\base\ErrorException: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/film.lc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php:330 
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/film.lc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php(225): yii\db\Command->update() 
#1 /var/www/film.lc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php(765): yii\db\ActiveRecord::updateAll() 
#2 /var/www/film.lc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php(570): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->updateInternal() 
#3 /var/www/film.lc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php(636): yii\db\ActiveRecord->update() 
#4 /var/www/film.lc/backend/modules/transliter/controllers/TransliterController.php(50): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->save() 
#5 /var/www/film.lc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): backend\modules\transliter\controllers\TransliterController->actionIndex() 
#6 /var/www/film.lc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): ::call_user_func_array:{/var/www/film.lc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php:57}()
 #7 /var/www/film.lc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(156): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams() 
#8 /var/www/film.lc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction() 
#9 /var/www/film.lc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(102): yii\base\Module->runAction() 
#10 /var/www/film.lc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(380): yii\web\Application->handleRequest() 
#11 /var/www/film.lc/backend/web/index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run() 
#12 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не правильно заполняете массив $post, он должен быть вида:

```
$post = ['Transliter' => ['attribute' => 'value']];
```